# Differences in "gradle dependencies" vs Gradle cache

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to understand the difference what dependencies are displayed when running "gradle dependences" on a project vs what ends up in "~/.gradle/cache"

Here is what I am doing:

I am using the following java project as an example:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-gradle/tree/master/complete

I deleted my local `.gradle` folder

I ran `.\gradlew.bat --refresh-dependencies dependencies test --no-daemon`

Now I compare the output of the dependencies task vs the content of the the `~/.gradle/cache` directory and there are hundreds more dependencies in the cache. What are these and where are they coming from?

Gradle Cache:

```
joda-time-2.2.jar
junit-4.12.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
annotations-13.0.jar
ant-1.10.7.jar
ant-launcher-1.10.7.jar
asm-7.1.jar
asm-analysis-7.1.jar
asm-commons-7.1.jar
asm-tree-7.1.jar
commons-compress-1.19.jar
commons-io-2.6.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
fastutil-8.3.0-min.jar
gradle-api-metadata-6.0.1.jar
gradle-base-services-6.0.1.jar
gradle-base-services-groovy-6.0.1.jar
gradle-bootstrap-6.0.1.jar
gradle-build-cache-6.0.1.jar
gradle-build-cache-packaging-6.0.1.jar
gradle-build-option-6.0.1.jar
gradle-cli-6.0.1.jar
gradle-core-6.0.1.jar
gradle-core-api-6.0.1.jar
gradle-docs-6.0.1.jar
gradle-execution-6.0.1.jar
gradle-file-collections-6.0.1.jar
gradle-files-6.0.1.jar
gradle-hashing-6.0.1.jar
gradle-installation-beacon-6.0.1.jar
gradle-jvm-services-6.0.1.jar
gradle-kotlin-dsl-6.0.1.jar
gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-6.0.1.jar
gradle-launcher-6.0.1.jar
gradle-logging-6.0.1.jar
gradle-messaging-6.0.1.jar
gradle-model-core-6.0.1.jar
gradle-model-groovy-6.0.1.jar
gradle-native-6.0.1.jar
gradle-persistent-cache-6.0.1.jar
gradle-pineapple-6.0.1.jar
gradle-process-services-6.0.1.jar
gradle-resources-6.0.1.jar
gradle-runtime-api-info-6.0.1.jar
gradle-snapshots-6.0.1.jar
gradle-tooling-api-6.0.1.jar
gradle-worker-processes-6.0.1.jar
gradle-wrapper-6.0.1.jar
groovy-all-1.3-2.5.8.jar
guava-27.1-android.jar
jansi-1.18.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.28.jar
jsr305-3.0.2.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar
kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50-patched-for-gradle-6.0.1.jar
kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-reflect-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-sam-with-receiver-compiler-plugin-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-scripting-common-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-scripting-jvm-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-scripting-jvm-host-embeddable-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.50.jar
kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.1.0.jar
kryo-2.24.0.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.28.jar
minlog-1.2.jar
native-platform-0.18.jar
native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libcpp-0.18.jar
native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libstdcpp-0.18.jar
native-platform-freebsd-i386-libcpp-0.18.jar
native-platform-freebsd-i386-libstdcpp-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-aarch64-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-aarch64-ncurses5-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-amd64-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses5-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses6-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-i386-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses5-0.18.jar
native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses6-0.18.jar
native-platform-osx-amd64-0.18.jar
native-platform-windows-amd64-0.18.jar
native-platform-windows-amd64-min-0.18.jar
native-platform-windows-i386-0.18.jar
native-platform-windows-i386-min-0.18.jar
objenesis-2.6.jar
aether-api-1.13.1.jar
aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
aether-impl-1.13.1.jar
aether-spi-1.13.1.jar
aether-util-1.13.1.jar
apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar
asm-util-7.1.jar
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.633.jar
aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.633.jar
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.633.jar
bcpg-jdk15on-1.63.jar
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.61.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.63.jar
bsh-2.0b6.jar
commons-codec-1.13.jar
dd-plist-1.21.jar
google-api-client-1.25.0.jar
google-api-services-storage-v1-rev136-1.25.0.jar
google-http-client-1.25.0.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.25.0.jar
google-oauth-client-1.25.0.jar
gradle-antlr-6.0.1.jar
gradle-build-cache-http-6.0.1.jar
gradle-build-init-6.0.1.jar
gradle-build-profile-6.0.1.jar
gradle-code-quality-6.0.1.jar
gradle-composite-builds-6.0.1.jar
gradle-dependency-management-6.0.1.jar
gradle-diagnostics-6.0.1.jar
gradle-ear-6.0.1.jar
gradle-ide-6.0.1.jar
gradle-ide-native-6.0.1.jar
gradle-ide-play-6.0.1.jar
gradle-instant-execution-6.0.1.jar
gradle-ivy-6.0.1.jar
gradle-jacoco-6.0.1.jar
gradle-javascript-6.0.1.jar
gradle-kotlin-dsl-provider-plugins-6.0.1.jar
gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-builders-6.0.1.jar
gradle-language-groovy-6.0.1.jar
gradle-language-java-6.0.1.jar
gradle-language-jvm-6.0.1.jar
gradle-language-native-6.0.1.jar
gradle-language-scala-6.0.1.jar
gradle-maven-6.0.1.jar
gradle-platform-base-6.0.1.jar
gradle-platform-jvm-6.0.1.jar
gradle-platform-native-6.0.1.jar
gradle-platform-play-6.0.1.jar
gradle-plugin-development-6.0.1.jar
gradle-plugin-use-6.0.1.jar
gradle-plugins-6.0.1.jar
gradle-publish-6.0.1.jar
gradle-reporting-6.0.1.jar
gradle-resources-gcs-6.0.1.jar
gradle-resources-http-6.0.1.jar
gradle-resources-s3-6.0.1.jar
gradle-resources-sftp-6.0.1.jar
gradle-scala-6.0.1.jar
gradle-signing-6.0.1.jar
gradle-test-kit-6.0.1.jar
gradle-testing-base-6.0.1.jar
gradle-testing-junit-platform-6.0.1.jar
gradle-testing-jvm-6.0.1.jar
gradle-testing-native-6.0.1.jar
gradle-tooling-api-builders-6.0.1.jar
gradle-tooling-native-6.0.1.jar
gradle-version-control-6.0.1.jar
gradle-workers-6.0.1.jar
gson-2.8.5.jar
httpclient-4.5.10.jar
httpcore-4.4.12.jar
ion-java-1.0.2.jar
ivy-2.3.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar
jackson-core-2.9.10.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.10.jar
jatl-0.2.3.jar
jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar
jcifs-1.3.17.jar
jcommander-1.72.jar
jmespath-java-1.11.633.jar
joda-time-2.10.4.jar
jsch-0.1.55.jar
junit-platform-commons-1.3.1.jar
junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar
junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar
jzlib-1.1.3.jar
maven-aether-provider-3.0.4.jar
maven-artifact-3.0.4.jar
maven-compat-3.0.4.jar
maven-core-3.0.4.jar
maven-model-3.0.4.jar
maven-model-builder-3.0.4.jar
maven-plugin-api-3.0.4.jar
maven-repository-metadata-3.0.4.jar
maven-settings-3.0.4.jar
maven-settings-builder-3.0.4.jar
nekohtml-1.9.22.jar
opentest4j-1.1.1.jar
org.eclipse.jgit-5.5.0.201909110433-r.jar
plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar
plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
plexus-container-default-1.7.1.jar
plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar
pmaven-common-0.8-20100325.jar
pmaven-groovy-0.8-20100325.jar
rhino-1.7.10.jar
simple-4.1.21.jar
snakeyaml-1.17.jar
testng-6.3.1.jar
wagon-file-3.0.0.jar
wagon-http-3.0.0.jar
wagon-http-shared-3.0.0.jar
wagon-provider-api-3.0.0.jar
xbean-reflect-3.7.jar
xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar
trove4j-1.0.20181211.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```

Gradle Dependencies Task:

```
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
\--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
\--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2 (n)

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
\--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2

runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
\--- junit:junit:4.12 (n)

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html, that folder (`~/.gradle/cache`) is a *global* Gradle cache, i.e. one can not and should not compare it with any single project.

Even if it's the only Gradle-based project you have thus far, Gradle needs a lot for itself, to be able to do it's work.